# Java HA framework

Tags: java, high-availability

I am writing a small proxy application which should be redundant, e.g. primary proxy will be running on one server and the redundant one will run on a separate server. Is there a simple high-availability framework which I can use to implement this redundancy? For example, this HA framework would send pings between instances and raise some sort of exception or notification on the other instance when the first one goes down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building such a system has been my routine job in recent years. I have found [jgroups](http://www.jgroups.org/)
a very usable tools to receive and handle such kind of grouping events. This is the case if you want to build your own HA infrastructure. I don't know, but maybe in your case just a simple reverse proxy such as HAProxy can be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you want HA without hassle, just use some load balancer with HA capability e.g. [Ultramonkey](http://www.ultramonkey.org/), [LVS](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/) with [keepalived](http://www.keepalived.org/) etc.

In a HA configuration, you'd typically want to use virtual IP, so even if you'd have this ping/notify functionality as a framework, you'll still have stuff to do (start responding to requests to the virtual IP once the other instance has failed). So unless you are looking for a learning occasion, I'd advice using a middleware instead of coding this yourself using frameworks.

There are number of health-checks that you can configure for these middlewares. A simple  healthcheck might for example, fire a GET request to your app. periodically and look for a specific string (e.g. "XXX running.") in the response to make sure your app. is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide much details about the work your application does, so depending on how stateful it is, whether it can tolerate minor dataloss, is it time-critical, do you value developer time over machine time, you can have a varying spectrum of solutions.

There are some good suggestions above, I'd add: take a look at JMS and persistent messaging. Usually these make recovery quite trivial, but at the cost of latency hit (unless you byu a commercial product and learn it well or pay the vendor to tune your application). With JMS queues you can implement active-active processing and save yourself the headache of failure detection.

Another direction to look at is distributed state management/clustering framework like Gigaspaces, Coherence, Gemstone, Infinispan, Gridgain and Teracotta. These can replicate your data and guarantee varying quality of services levels. Most of them come with some type of failure detection and distributed management mechanism.

Answer (score -3):

[**hadoop**](http://hadoop.apache.org/) is a good place to start

Comment: Seriously? Hadoop is a distributed computation framework. Why would you use a map-reduce framework for this?